# VCLinkerTool.GenerateDebugInformation Property does not support DEBUG:FULL and DEBUG:FASTLINK

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vssdk

I'm using VS SDK to set project properties of a VS C++ project file. I want to set C++ linker properties Debug information. Following seems to be the required property I have to set:
[VCLinkerTool.GenerateDebugInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vclinkertool.generatedebuginformation?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#remarks)

However, as you can see this is a boolean property. But debug information allows 4 values to be set to this by VS:

1. No
2. Debug
3. Debug Full
4. Fastlink

I want to set Debug Full, but unable to do so since VCLinkerTool.GenerateDebugInformation does not accept string values. Anybody know any other way to achieve this?

Comment: This change has been rife with integration problems.  Also a big issue with the DbgHelp api and the debuggers provided by the Windows group.  Far, far removed from the DevDiv division.  Heavy smell of a skunk works project in a very big company.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this seems to be the use of [IVCRulePropertyStorage Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.ivcrulepropertystorage?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Instructions are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn655034.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).